# Modify numpy array based on previous value

Tags: python, numpy

I have a np array, let's say

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Now I want to modify the number at index i s.t. it is 0, if one of the previous n elements was a 1. But this calculation should not be static w.r.t to the original array, but dynamic, i.e. considering already changed values. Let's say n=2, then I want to get

```
[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

How do I do that efficiently without a for loop?
Simple indexing will run over the whole array in one iteration, ignoring newly changed values, meaning the result would be

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

right?

Update:
In a loop I would do this:

```
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    FoundPrevious = False
    for j in range(n):
        if i - j < 0:
            continue
        if a[i - j] == 1:
            FoundPrevious = True
            break
    if FoundPrevious:
        a[i] = 0
```

Comment: Can you show how you would do it in a loop. That will make it easier to convert.

Comment: Sure, edited the code

Comment: A list solution is probably the best you'll get.  The problem is inherently iterative, and it's faster to iterate on a list than an array.

Comment: Could you give me more details on this @hpaulj?

Comment: Shouldn't the correct output be `[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]`?

Comment: ah your right! thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is inherently iterative, but you can simplify things by doing a single pass over your list.

```
arr = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
n = 2
newarr = []

for i in arr:
    newarr.append(0 if sum(newarr[-n:]) else i)
```

```
print (newarr)
[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Comment: When I saw the pic, I thought it was scott , LOL :-)

Comment: @Wen Almost, scott is from TAMU :p

Answer (score 1):

As other answerers and commenters have noted, the intrinsic interative nature of the problem makes a solution without a for-loop non-obvious.

Another approach to simplifying this problem is:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
n = 2

for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    i0 = i - 2 if i >= 2 else 0
    if 1 in a[i0:i]:
        a[i] = 0

print(a)
# [1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0]
```